# Can we load data from Excel to Snowflake?

Tags: excel, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to insert some data with images through Excel into snowflake?? I didn't found any solutions If anyone know please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does snowflake have an import routine or examples in its help?

Comment: @SolarMike I am new to snowflake so i don't have any idea about it.

Comment: I've not used it, but you did not mention if you had looked...

Answer (score 1):

Try to save excel file as csv, than put file to s3 and than do something like it:

```
copy into mytable from 's3://mybucket 1/prefix 1/file 1.csv';
```

make sure you configured correct access rights for you buckets.

More details you can find here https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html